# Using @font-face with Rails 3.1 app?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3.1, font-face, sass

I'm having trouble using the following `@font-face` declaration to work with my Rails 3.1 app.  I put the fonts in the Asset Pipeline in its own folder called "Fonts" alongside `images` and `stylesheets` and `javascripts`

Here is the declaration I used (generated by Font Squirrel.)

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'ChunkFiveRegular';
  src: url('Chunkfive-webfont.eot');
  src: url('Chunkfive-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('Chunkfive-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('Chunkfive-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('Chunkfive-webfont.svg#ChunkFiveRegular') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Anyone successfully utilize @font-face on their Rails 3.1 app?

**Update**

I just read this thread http://spin.atomicobject.com/2011/09/26/serving-fonts-in-rails-3-1/ that said to change `url` to `font-url` in the declarations.  That didn't seem to work either unfortunately.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You have to add the folder to the assets path (to file `config/application.rb`), see [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#asset-organization)

```
config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/fonts"
```

And you should use the `asset_path` helper:

```
src: url('<%= asset_path('Chunkfive-webfont.eot') %>');
```

Comment: thanks for the documentation.  still doesn't work however :(  I wonder if there is something else that im missing

Comment: I just saw a upper/lower case issue, you spelled Fonts and I fonts. And you should use asset_path in your stylesheet, updated my post

Comment: what does the part of generated stylesheet look like now?

Comment: Invalid CSS after "...unkfive-webfont": expected ")", was ".eot') %>');"

Comment: are you using the erb extension? `style.scss.erb`

Comment: Don't forget to restart your development server so it can apply the changes to config/application.rb. I had this problem.

Answer (score 40):

I know this is an old question, but I just stumbled across this issue with rails 3.2, and after reading the link to the documentation posted previously, there was no need to edit the application.rb. All I needed to do was do the following in my stylesheet (using sass)

```
@font-face {
    font: {
       family: 'Junction';
       weight: 'normal';
       style: 'normal';
    }
    src: asset-url('Junction-webfont.eot', font);
    src: asset-url('Junction-webfont.eot', font) format('embedded-opentype'),
         asset-url('Junction-webfont.woff', font) format('woff'),
         asset-url('Junction-webfont.ttf', font) format('truetype'),
         asset-url('Junction-webfont.svg#JunctionRegular', font) format('svg')
}
```

So instead of using url, I used the generic asset-url, which takes 2 arguments, the file and the asset class, in this case 'font'.

Comment: where did you place your fonts though?

Comment: Font assets go in app/assets/fonts/. Then add this to the Application class in your config/application.rb: `config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/fonts"`. Then this answer works beautifully, even in Rails 3.2

Comment: Thanks @DanMundy. `config.asset.paths` + `asset-url` combined are working in Rails v3.2.10.

Comment: Upgrade to 3.2.11! There's a pretty big security hole in 3.2.10.

Answer (score 14):

From Rails 3.1 and above you can call `font-url` directly. Like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'ChunkFiveRegular';
  src: font-url('Chunkfive-webfont.eot');
  src: font-url('Chunkfive-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     font-url('Chunkfive-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     font-url('Chunkfive-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     font-url('Chunkfive-webfont.svg#ChunkFiveRegular') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Expect your final css to look like that:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'ChunkFiveRegular';
  src: url(/assets/Chunkfive-webfont.eot);
  src: url(/assets/Chunkfive-webfont.eot?#iefix) format('embedded-opentype'),
     url(/assets/Chunkfive-webfont.woff) format('woff'),
     url(/assets/Chunkfive-webfont.ttf) format('truetype'),
     url(/assets/Chunkfive-webfont.svg#ChunkFiveRegular) format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Usually works :)

Comment: This is the correct answer for Rail's asset pipeline. Make sure your CSS file is named `.css.scss` so that the `font-url` helper will function correctly.

Comment: This is the answer. Like @scarver2 said, `font-url` will only work with SASS or LESS files. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/10907276/165673 for more.

Comment: Also make sure the scaffold.css.scss isn't overriding things with its font declarations.

Answer (score 6):

Using Rails 4.0 (don't know if this is specific to 4, but anyway), I was only able to make it work with `url(font_path('font-name.ttf'))`. Adding the fonts path to the assets path was not necessary either (<strike>`config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/fonts"`</strike>).

So, to me this is what worked:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'ChunkFiveRegular';
  src: url(font_path('Chunkfive-webfont.eot'));
  src: url(font_path('Chunkfive-webfont.eot?#iefix')) format('embedded-opentype'),
     url(font_path('Chunkfive-webfont.woff')) format('woff'),
     url(font_path('Chunkfive-webfont.ttf')) format('truetype'),
     url(font_path('Chunkfive-webfont.svg#ChunkFiveRegular')) format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: In my experience with Rails 4 you could simply use font-url for 'url', but make sure the extension of the file is: .css.scss, otherwise parsing font-url won't work. EDIT: See post below, already explained it.

Answer (score 1):

I just updated that article on Atomic Object's Spin blog. Here is the CSS converted (You were looking at the Sass syntax)

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Merriweather";
  src: url(/assets/merriweather-black-webfont.eot);
  src: local("Merriweather Heavy"), local("Merriweather-Heavy"), url(/assets/merriweather-black-webfont.eot?#iefix) format("embedded-opentype"), url(/assets/merriweather-black-webfont.woff) format("woff"), url(/assets/merriweather-black-webfont.ttf) format("truetype"), url(/assets/merriweather-black-webfont.svg#MerriweatherHeavy) format("svg");
  font-weight: 900;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: i'm using .scss tho.  hmm...strange

Comment: Local is to check if they have the font on their machine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using 3.1.1 and have my fonts under vendor/assets/store (Spree implementation).  The solutions given here did not work for me and I eventually just tried what ended up being my solution - there was no need for

Here's an example of my src attribute for EOT:

```
src: url('1617A5_4.eot');
```

I'm a little bit confused by this but it seems like once assets are compiled the assets are all copied in to their parent folder (assets/store/) at which point the stylesheet can just pick them up.

Comment: Use Jared's solution, which also worked for me.  I simply forgot the store/ prefix for each font files URL.  And use the font-url helper, not fonts-url.

Answer (score 0):

While this is late, you could use Compass's `+font-face` mix-in to avoid all this trouble. The mixin helps your life easier by

1. Not remember the awful caveats of the traditional font-face decleration
2. It internally handles url_helper and format declarations for you
3. It's far easier to remember

It is declared the following way madams and gentlemen:

```
+font-face("#{$font-name}",
  font-files("#{$font-name}.woff", woff, 
  "#{$fontFileName}.ttf", ttf, 
  "#{$fontFileName}.svg", svg), "#{$fontFileName}.eot", normal, normal);
```