# How can I embed fonts with @font-face in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, font-face, ruby-on-rails-4

The title pretty much says it all...

I tried adding `/app/assets/fonts/font.woff` and referencing it from my css file with `/app/assets/fonts/font.woff` but it doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you just add the .woff file or did you write some code to reference it? Your question lacks some info...

Comment: @JustinD. I try to reference those files from my css file by adjusting the paths manually like `/app/assets/fonts/...` but it's not working. Seems like Rails is getting in the way.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7973271/using-font-face-with-rails-3-1-app

Comment: @JimLim That's for Rails 3.1. Does any of that apply to 4.0? I'm new to rails but I've already encountered a LOT of differences between early 3.x and 4.0.

Comment: Yea, it can get confusing. When following links, make sure you are looking at the Rails 4 guides and reading the Rails 4 api. APIDock does a good job of showing changes across versions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turns out that the asset pipeline that @JimLim mentioned works a bit differently in Rails 4. Full docs [here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html), but here's the relevant excerpt:

> ### 2 How to Use the Asset Pipeline
>
> In previous versions of Rails, all
>   assets were located in subdirectories of public such as images,
>   javascripts and stylesheets. With the asset pipeline, the preferred
>   location for these assets is now the app/assets directory. Files in
>   this directory are served by the Sprockets middleware.
>
> Assets can still be placed in the public hierarchy. Any assets under
>   public will be served as static files by the application or web
>   server. You should use app/assets for files that must undergo some
>   pre-processing before they are served.
>
> In production, Rails precompiles these files to public/assets by
>   default. The precompiled copies are then served as static assets by
>   the web server. The files in app/assets are never served directly in
>   production.

So I ended up moving my /fonts directory into /public adjusting my paths in the @font-face declaration accordingly and everything works fine.

Answer (score 3):

You have to tell Rails to include your fonts directory in the asset pipeline, as follows:

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'fonts')
```

Finally, let Rails figure out the correct path for you, so you don't have to mess with the prefix `app`, `app/assets` etc. Add a `.erb` extension to your css/scss file *e.g.* `application.css.erb`, and use embedded ruby:

```
src: url("<%= asset_path('fonts.woff') %>");
```

([Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7973271/using-font-face-with-rails-3-1-app))

Comment: I didn't realize that you could use ruby in CSS files. Very cool!

Comment: I haven't played with this much, but in general you can append file extensions to tell Rails to use the proper preprocessors.

Comment: Hey Jim thanks for your answer. Quick question, with the path you have routed - I'd be putting the fonts in the app/assets folder correct? So it would be app/assets/fonts?

Comment: It would be in `app/assets/fonts`.